# Show $\max_{i \leq m}\langle e_n,y_i\rangle$ is square summable

Tags: functional-analysis, solution-verification, hilbert-spaces

Suppose $\{e_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ an ortho-normal basis for a real Hilbert space H and ${y_i}$ is a collection of $m$ vectors in $H$. Show $z_n=\max_{i}|(\langle e_n,y_i \rangle)|$ is square summable.

My attempt;

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|z_n|^2 \leq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}||\sum_{i=1}^m \langle e_n,y_i \rangle|^2 \leq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{i=1}^{m}|\langle e_n,y_i \rangle|^2= \sum_{i=1}^{m}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|\langle e_n,y_i \rangle|^2=\sum_{i=1}^{m} ||y_i||$$

$$ < \infty$$

I"m mostly skeptical because this seems to work for any finite collection but the problem I'm working on had me do some work to get particular $y_i's$ and I did not use that property. (Each $y_i$ is in a weak n-hood of $\vec{0}$). Also replacing the max with the full sum seems rather coarse of an estimate.  Finally I've yet to see Percival's(sp?) identity discussed in my text (I use in last equality). It is in the book but several chapters after this problem appears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each of the inequalities in $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|z_n|^2 \leq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}||\sum_{i=1}^m \langle e_n,y_i \rangle|^2 \leq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{i=1}^{m}|\langle e_n,y_i \rangle|^2$$
is invalid.  To see this:

- For the former suppose not all $z_n$ are zero and $\sum_{i=1}^m y_i = 0$
- For the latter suppose $\langle e_n, y_i\rangle \geq 0$ for each
  $n,i$ and strict inequality for at least two $i$ for some $n$.

On the other hand, all you need for the proof to work is the outer inequality:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|z_n|^2 \leq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{i=1}^{m}|\langle e_n,y_i \rangle|^2$$
and this is both true and not hard to prove.  It follows from $|a_j|^2 \leq \sum_{i=1}^m |a_i|^2$ whenever $1 \leq j \leq m$.

Comment: I miscopied the problem, it should be $z_n=max_i(|<y_i,e_n>|)$ so I think at least the first one holds now.  The second should hold for all sequences? I'm not sure I understand your counterexample.

Comment: @Muselive I assumed you miscopied it, but that doesn't fix the first one at all.  When $\sum_i y_i = 0$ then you'd have $\sum_{n=1}^\infty |z_n|^2 \leq 0$ which is false unless all $z_n = 0$.  The second one, you essentially have $(2+2)^2 \leq 2^2 + 2^2$.